# Docker compose Conflict error

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, docker, lighttpd

Unable to start container with docker-compose up

```
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER Parzee info@parzee.com

# Install Components.

# Update the repository
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
# Install necessary tools
RUN apt-get install -y nano vim wget dialog net-tools
RUN apt-get install lighttpd -y
RUN apt-get install php5-common php5-cgi php5 -y
RUN lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php
RUN update-rc.d -f lighttpd disable
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/utils/security/des

ADD lighttpd.conf /etc/lighttpd/

VOLUME ["/var/log/lighttpd"]

RUN ls -al /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

RUN /usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

EXPOSE 8083
```

docker-compose.yml

```
lighttpd:
  image: parzee/lighttpd
  ports: 
    - "8083:8083"
  volumes:
    - volumes/log:/var/log/lighttpd
```

When I run:

```
docker run -h lighttpd -p 8083:8083 -d -v `pwd`/volumes/log:/var/log/lighttpd -t parzee/lighttpd
```

my container starts fine, but with docker-compose I get the following error:

```
Creating lighttpd_lighttpd_1
ERROR: Conflict. The name "lighttpd_lighttpd_1" is already in use by container e7ec110d68ad. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
# docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
parzee/lighttpd       latest              47cf7b87858d        43 minutes ago      299.7 MB
parzee/loadbalancer   latest              db1cb8f5f4e2        9 hours ago         295.4 MB
parzee/application    latest              a2a632be751b        11 hours ago        722.9 MB
parzee/imbue          latest              5347302fee40        4 days ago          1.347 GB
parzee/database       latest              eb2faddc2a5c        4 days ago          374.5 MB
ubuntu                14.04               c4bea91afef3        5 weeks ago         187.9 MB
ubuntu                latest              c4bea91afef3        5 weeks ago         187.9 MB
# docker ps -al
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
2eb1565da8d5        parzee/lighttpd     "/bin/bash"         33 minutes ago      Exited (0) 21 minutes ago                       modest_almeida
```

I tried to reboot machine, docker rmi image, docker-compose kill, no luck any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
docker rm lighttpd_lighttpd_1
```

Then

```
docker-compose up
```

As for the volume name, they can't be relative.  You need to provide an absolute path for the host side

Comment: Thanks I just deleted it, now is complaining for a volume name. I opened a different thread for it.

Comment: @spicyramen, the volume name needs to be an absolute path not relative one